# Unable to delete the current record

Tags: apex, trigger

I am written one trigger as below it processing certain condition has been stratified then delete the current record.But I am Unable to delete the current record.

**Code:**

```
Trigger OrderDelete on Company__c (AFTER INSERT,AFTER UPDATE){
 LIST<Company__c> deletecom = NEW LIST<Company__c>();
    FOR(Company__c com : Trigger.new)
    {
        IF((com.Delete__c == TRUE)&&(com.Order_Source_Code__c == 'DUM'))
            deletecom.add(com);                            
    }
    IF(deletecom.SIZE() != 0)
        DELETE deletecom;
}
```

It throw an exception why I don't no.

**EXCEPTION :**

Error: Invalid Data.
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger OrderDelete caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: OrderDelete: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.SObjectException: DML statment cannot operate on trigger.new or trigger.old: Trigger.OrderDelete: line 21, column 1

Some one please help me .....

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you provided the exception you are getting. Also, in the for-loop you are adding Company records to the list `deleteord`, but you are passing list `deletecom` to the `delete` operation - use same variable in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect you're receiving this error (including spelling mistake, well done SF):

```
System.SObjectException: DML statment cannot operate on trigger.new or trigger.old
```

That's because the record you are trying to delete is in the `Trigger.new` collection. You would need to re-query the records first:

```
List<Company__c> companies = [Select Id From Company__c Where Id IN :Trigger.new];
```

Then, loop `companies` instead of `Trigger.new`. The error message is self explanatory.

Comment: I have been modified my question and added exception also

Comment: Yes, that is the same error as I describe above. Make the changes I have suggested and everything should be peachy. However, looks like you're trying to delete a record a user has just inserted....thats not going to look nice when the trigger finally does work